# Can I specify order of evaluation, and how a matrix gets multuplied in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numerical-methods, cpu-time

I'm taking a numerical linear algebra course and I've chosen to use python as my language of choice (want to be employable). Is there a way to evaluate (AB)C vs A(BC), where  A,B,C are conformable matrices? I want to check cpu time and operation count for each of these. In addition, is there a way to force python to calculate AB as a sum of outer products and as a Matrix whose entries are the inner product of the rows and columns of A, and B respectively. I'm new to python and haven't had any luck with a google search, which is rare. Im using python 3.5*  that uses @ for matrix multiplication.  I searched for resources where numerical linear algebra is done using python but haven't found anything useful. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Take a look at `numpy` and `scipy` libraries. As currently written - question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first question is trivial: write `(A @ B) @ C` versus `A @ (B @ C)`.  CPython is smart enough that know that it is too dumb to try to rewrite expressions.  The language definitiion does not require that the special methods (such as `__add__` for `+`) have any particular properties.  (In fact, float add is *not* associative.)

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis('(a + b) + c')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              6 BINARY_ADD
              7 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
             10 BINARY_ADD
             11 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis('a + (b + c)')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              6 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
              9 BINARY_ADD
             10 BINARY_ADD
             11 RETURN_VALUE
```

Replace `+` with `@` and the output is the same with `ADD` changed to `MATRIX_MULTIPLY`.

I do not understand the details of the second question, but you should be able to define your own Matrix class with a `__matmul__` method that does what you want.  It could either be 'pure' python or build on `numpy`.

Comment: Thank you Terry, this is exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't sure I python would evaluate it the way I specify because this will affect number of operarions for large matrices. for my second question if you look at A which is an  (m,n) matrix as row vector of n entries where each entry is an (m,1) column vector and matrix B which is (n,p) as a column vector with n entries where each entry is an (1,p) row vector, then AB looks like an inner product in the big picture and in the small picture if I multiply the first entry of A times the first entry of B i get an (m,1)(1,p) = (m,p) matrix. I

Comment: do this for all entries in A and B yielding a sum of n (m,p) matrices which equal AB . I want to mimic this in python

Comment: If I switch roles of A and B then in the big picture A times B looks like an outer product where each entry is an inner product of AB. When I timeit it in python I'm expecting it to be much faster in the latter case since the first case is much more memory intensive and require more operations.